# add a class definition inside a class and initialize it?

Tags: objective-c

Yes, I am floundering with both concepts and (mostly) implementation.

Trying to write a SIMPLE program ( my first ) which I wrote in C to get the algorithm working.
Not.  So.  Simple to join this party.

Pulling out hair, hungry and neglecting dog, which I did several decades ago..  wondering if I am too old for this.   Spinnning wheels and feeling stupid.
Doesn't seem that ambitious a project!

I'm not looking for someone to code this for me.. just to give me some BIG hints

---

Defined 2 classes.

1st -  an array of 6 integers (myRow)

2nd - bunch of data..
    - several myRows for various purposes
    - "GRID" of myRows of unknown number, thus creating a 2D array of unknown length.

I thought I could NSMUTALBE array of myRows, and alloc/add a row as needed
I now have more commented out things that don't work than things that do.

```
//--------
myprog.h 

@interface OneRow:NSObject{
    NSInteger row[6];   
}
@property( assign, nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger *row;

    //need some methods here
@end

// ---------
@interface BigClass:NSObject

@property ( assign, nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL wereDone;
//  bunch of definitions removed 
//  ok.. ONE ROW seems ok..
@property ( assign, nonatomic, readwrite) OneRow *aRow;
@property ( assign, nonatomic, readwrite) OneRow *bRow;

// ??????  can I declare the grid here???

@end

//------------
myprog.m

@implementation OneRow

@synthesize row = _row;

- (id)  init
{if ( self = [super init])
    for (int i = 0 ; i<6; i++) self.row[i]= 0;
return self;
}

@end


@implementation BigClass


// Note to self - @synthesize does 3 things - generate instance var, generate getter & setter..

@synthesize wereDone = _wereDone;

@synthesize aRow = _aRow;
@synthesize bRow = _bRow;

// ???  can I implement the grid here??
// tried it

// bunch o' methods

// ???? tried implementing grid in the init routine... no dice

@end
```

Comment: What are you going to use the data structure for?

Comment: What is the question here? There are a number of bugs in this code, but I don't know which if any are what you're asking about. If you're encountering a problem in attempting to do something, can you describe clearly what you want to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: Now I want to totally delete this, and will in a few hours.  Once I stepped away from the computer, and thought about it, I realized that I was COMPLETELY going about this the wrong way.  A lesson I refuse to learn even after decades.    Step Away From Machine.  embarrassed.